# DotNetCharting exception thrown

Tags: c#, wcf, charts

I am using DotNetCharting version 4.2.  I am trying to create a chart, save it to disk and return the path as a string.  Here is a simplified version of my code thus far.

```
Chart aChart = new Chart();
aChart aChart.Title = "Some Title";
aChart aChart.ChartArea.Background = new Background(Color.White);

aChart.TempDirectory = "C:\\temp\\"
aChart.Width = chartWidth;
aChart.Height = chartHeight;

imageName = aChart.FileManager.SaveImage();
```

I got this from [this](http://dotnetcharting.com/kb/KnowledgebaseArticle10073.aspx) dotnetCharting support page.  It is very straightforward code.

Here is the problem:  The code above actually DOES create an image in the appropriate directory.  This is NOT a directory permissions issue.  When I add my actual data to the aChart, it actually DOES add it and an image is created.  However, the `SaveImage()` method always throws an exception of "Failed to map the path '/'."  The `SaveImage()` method is supposed to return a String, however, it always returns "" and the exception is thrown.

More Info:  I am doing this in a WCF Service.  Is it possible that since it's in a service the dotNetCharting DLL is having trouble with some internal MapPath?

Comment: You are creating an initializing `aChart` and calling SaveImage on `coinInChart`

Comment: Sorry, co-paste issue.  I was trying to make it generic.  In real code, it's all using the same object.

Comment: No problem, just jumped out at me. Your WCF service speculation sounds likely. Does this component support that sceniorio?

Comment: I just upgraded the DotNetCharting to the latest version and now it works fine.  I believe that it was an issue with the old version of the DLL.  thanks for taking a look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just upgraded the DotNetCharting to the latest version (7.0) and now it works fine.  I believe that it was an issue with the old version of the DLL.  I'll leave this here in case anyone else has this issue.